# Magento - Create order through rest

Tags: java, magento, rest, magento-1.7

I'm developing a Magento client (built in Java) that's supposed to generate orders through REST API. 
I couldn't find anything related to generate orders over REST, found only over SOAP. 
Is it already supported at Magento 1.7? If dont, is there any extension that does it? 

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento have introduced REST API in their Community Edition 1.7 as stated here

http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/the-magento-rest-api-a-better-way-to-integrate-business-applications/

Also check this to see how it works

http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/Resources/Orders/sales_orders.html

Comment: Yes, but the second link says that Magento POST order is not implemented yet. Do you know any extension that does it?

Comment: You can extend the Magento API by yourself if you need to.

Comment: I've solved my problem with SOAP... Don't want to implement a complex interface from scratch.. Thanks anyway

Comment: @MatheusJardimB can you please share how did you post order using magento soap apis? did you use create cart and cart order?